# Can I make a call to an MVC controller or Model using the Razor Host Module in DNN?

Tags: razor, module, dotnetnuke, host

We have a content page that runs a boolean check in our controller and we are moving that page to DNN. Is there a way to keep running that check using the Razor Host module?

I would basically show or hide button based on the status of a registration process.

Answer (score 0):

My manager found the solution:

It turns out if you create a static file and save it in the Components folder (remember this is for DNN modules), you can just make a call to that class and its methods from within the Razor Host module as such:

@using MYNAMESPACE.Modules.Myproject.MyModule.Components

Some html

@{ var isRegistrationOpen = MyStaticClass.IsRegistrationOpen(); }

Registration Status: @isRegistrationOpen